# Graphing $\left(\;(4x -2 \leq 6 \;\text{ and }\; 3-x \leq 7)\;\text{ or }\;(3x > 18 \;\text{ and }\; 2x-9 \geq 11)\;\right)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

This is a homework question from a precalculus class that I'm a TA for.

> Graph on a real line all points $x$ such that
>   \begin{equation}\tag{$\star$}
>   (4x -2 \leq 6 \;\text{ and }\; 3-x \leq 7)
>   \;\;\text{ or }\;\;
>   (3x > 18 \;\text{ and }\; 2x-9 \geq 11)\,.
> \end{equation}

Enough students were struggling with it, especially with how to mathematically interpret "*and*" and "*or*", that I wanted to write up a thorough solution to this exercise for my class, and figured I'd post it online to help anyone else who may wander across it.

Comment: Mike, while I agree with the premise that some self answered questions can be of use, I'm not so sure about this one. This seems like a question very easily answered if one reads any of the questions on graphing inequalities.

Comment: @RushabhMehta Then shouldn't this question be closed as a duplicate as one of those? It makes no sense to close for *missing context*. The context is clear and provided.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The four inequalities above can be written more simply as 
the following four inequalities: 
\begin{equation}\tag{$\star$}
    (x \leq 2 \;\text{ and }\; x \geq -4)
    \;\;\text{ or }\;\;
    (x > 6 \;\text{ and }\; x \geq 10)
\end{equation}
The word "*and*" between two inequalities
indicates that we need them to simultaneously be true, which 
corresponds to taking the intersection
of their individual solution sets. 
So the first pair of inequalities are true 
for all $x$ such that $-4 \leq x \leq 2$.
On a number line, this looks like:

[image: number line -4 \leq x \leq 2]

Similarly for the other pair of inequalities,
the intersection of their solution sets
are all $x$ such that $x \geq 10$.

[image: number line for x \geq 10]

Now the word "*or*" between two inequalities 
indicates that we just need either one of them to be true,
which corresponds to taking the union of their solution sets.
So all the points $x$ that satisfy $(\star)$,
when graphed on a number line, would look like

[image: final number line, the union of the previous solution sets]